# How use Laravel Contextual Binding for Logger channels?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, contextual-binding

In Laravel documentation I see example:

```php
$this->app->when(PhotoController::class)
          ->needs(Filesystem::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return Storage::disk('local');
          });

$this->app->when([VideoController::class, UploadController::class])
          ->needs(Filesystem::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return Storage::disk('s3');
          });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#contextual-binding

I want make the same with diffenet Log channels insead Storage disks.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#writing-to-specific-channels

I try:

```php
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
```

```php
$this->app->when(PhotoController::class)
          ->needs('log')
          ->give(function () {
              return \Log::channel('telegram');
          });

$this->app->when([VideoController::class, UploadController::class])
          ->needs('log')
          ->give(function () {
              return \Log::channel('slack');
          });
```

But I get error:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:792
 Stack trace:
 #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('Illuminate\\Log\\...')
 #1 /var/www/html/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(106): Illuminate\Container\Container->get('Illuminate\\Log\\...')
 #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): App\Providers\AppServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
 #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(691): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
 #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('log', Array, true)
 #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646):  in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 792
```

Also I tried:

```php
->needs(LoggerInterface::class)
```

And the same error.

I do not see examples of how to do this correctly in the documentation. There is nothing about it.

Comment: I believe this is because you cannot inject an interface, but instead it has to be an implementation, as per example with storage you get a concrete instance with particular storage type, while with log it's an interface that system cannot resolve.

Comment: A recursive loop occurs on the line `return \Log::channel ('slack');` because it calls the container to resolve the Log for the Log. Need some workaround.

Comment: Perhaps try [binding](https://jinoantony.com/blog/code-to-interface-an-example-in-laravel) your interface first?

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote*: you can bind to an interface, its a common usage, Laravel calls them 'Contracts', see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations . So that is not the issue here.

Onto the question: I can't quite figure out what I'm doing differently but it works as intended for me:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
$this->app->when(SomeController::class)->needs('log')->give(function() {
    return Log::channel('mychannel');
});
```

However, the `'log'` string I dont quite like here. I believe it refers to the name of the so called "facade" for the logger, which brings more cognitive overload to what exactly this refers to. Imho its better to use a full class name here, to be more explicit:

```php
use Illuminate\Log\Logger;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
$this->app->when(SomeController::class)->needs(Logger::class)->give(function() {
    return Log::channel('mychannel');
});
```

You can then use the following snippet in any of your controllers:

```php
public function __construct(Logger $logger) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

In fact you have a couple of options of defining the when/needs/give:

- `Illuminate\Log\Logger::class`
- `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class` (Logger above implements this)

Both work, but in both cases you need to use the exact class in your (to be injected) constructor exactly as written. You cannot bind the `LoggerInterface` and typehint `Logger` in your controller constructor and expect it to work, it does not recognize inheritance in this way apparently.

Another nice thing to know, is that apparently this only works on **constructors** directly. Controller *methods* have dependency injection as well but this **does not work** in combination with the contextual binding. However, it works with the default "simple" bindings as defined here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container#binding :

```php
public function showUser(Illuminate\Log\Logger $log) {
    // This typehint does not take contextual binding into account. You will receive
    // the default binding for this class.
    $log->info('...');
}
```

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6177 (tl;dr: the issue is closed and contextual bindings for controller methods will not be supported in the future).

I hope this information helps you out.

Comment: It's work if use `Illuminate\Log\Logger::class` but don't work if use `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class`. It’s strange.

Comment: if you are using that same class in the typehint then I dont know why it doesnt work